# merging one object into another without creating a new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working with angular 1.

I have a simple API that delivers objects via socket once every 10seconds.

The response is an object that should update the existing object used to generate the ang1 view.

However, when i replace the object one for one the whole page flickers a little. Is it possible to merge one object into another so as only the altered leafs of the object change?

I had a go with jquery extend but this copies ont into another a too high of a level.

Here is an example:

```
var a = {
  'bob': {
    'gender': 'male'
  },
  'cat': {
    'gender': 'female'
  }
};
var b = {
  'bob': {
    'gender': 'female'
  },
  'cat': {
    'gender': 'female'
  }
};
```

What I am trying to achieve is a single function that will merge only the differences into from var b into var a. So in the above example, the function would only alter a.bob.gender.

Comment: Your question is off-topic, but you can try [loadsh](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) for that

Comment: I don't agree my question is off topic at all, it is a javascript problem that affects angular1. I have tried lodash, it is the same as jquery, the output is a new object which then causes angular1 to rebuild the view completely.

Comment: Have you looked into angular.extend and merge? They can modify existing or create new objects

Comment: Well, it's not up to me to decide if it's off-topic or not. But anyway, you might be able to do it using [angular.marge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) and I think that unlike loadsh, the build in _angular.marge_ function keeps the original bindings with the view that will prevent the view from flickering

Comment: thank you! i did not know this existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan gave the answer in the comments and solved the issue:

"angular.marge function keeps the original bindings with the view that will prevent the view from flickering"

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge